# PostgreSQL function ON INSERT, insert JSON values to another table

Tags: postgresql-json

I'm attempting to write a function in PostgreSQL that receives a record when a Cloudant document is inserted, via listening to Cloudant (I would like to make it a lambda, but right now it is a node process).

I'm taking the Cloudant id and the complete document and inserting it to `case_raw` table with columns: char(32) `id` and json type `raw_json`.

```
CREATE TABLE report_db.case_raw
(
    doc_id character(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    raw_json jsonb NOT NULL
)
```

The effort to go from Cloudant to Postgres is so I can do complex joins and such on data that comes from edge devices in JSON form.

Here is a sample of the Cloudant doc, and I'm using the same `id` in the id column, where this would be inserted into `raw_json`.

```
{
    "name": {
        "id": "4e1e3425ef49b3b028683a5cb06ca585",
        "doc": {
            "_id": "4e1e3425ef49b3b028683a5cb06ca585",
            "_rev": "1-feae33bee0b773c7d130b1dd6fb42869",
            "doc_type": "standard",
            "location": {
                "carrier": "AT&T",
                "mobileCountryCode": 123,
                "mobileNetworkCode": 456
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to make a *trigger* that calls a *function* for every row `ON INSERT`.

But, I'm having a huge hang up immediately. I've tried everything I can think of including: WITH, nested SELECT, to_json, casting ::json, and I bet it is simple, but why can't I (seemingly) not use JSON operators?

I can directly query records and get to the data I want from this record, for example (in two different ways getting the same thing):

```
SELECT * FROM case_raw WHERE raw_json->'name'->'doc'->'location'->>'carrier' = 'AT&T';

SELECT * FROM case_raw WHERE raw_json @> '{"name":{"doc": {"location": { "carrier": "AT&T"}}}}'
```

But, for the life of me I cannot step into the JSON. I've read atleast 20 posts, PG docs, PG tutorials, but not finding anything to move me forward. Any insight is greatly appreciated. Here I've greatly truncated attempts at using `with`, etc. PGAdmin reports an error on `->'name'`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parse_raw ()
RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  -- We have a lot more values to insert, but PG does not seem to like the syntax of the following:
  INSERT INTO report_db.location_master VALUES (NEW.raw_json->'name'->'doc'->'location'->>'carrier');
  RETURN NEW;
END' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- setup on before insert trigger to parse into tables
CREATE TRIGGER parse_raw_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON report_db.case_raw
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE parse_raw();
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've seen your name on so many of the posts around Postgres and I was actually really hoping you might see this one! I've added a sample with the matching property structure todo with `location`. Thank you in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

You are embedding a string inside a string. So for the embedded `'name'` the single quotes need to be [escaped](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS). So you essentially have `' ... 'name' ...`  which isn't a valid string constant. It should be `' ... ''name'' ...'`

To make that easier, the usual approach is to wrap the whole function body (string) with [dollar quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)

It's also good coding practice to always qualify the target columns in an INSERT statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parse_raw ()
RETURNS trigger AS 
$body$ --<< replaces the '
BEGIN
 -- We have a lot more values to insert, but PG does not seem to like the syntax of the following:
 INSERT INTO report_db.location_master (carrier) VALUES (NEW.raw_json->'name'->'doc'->'location'->>'carrier');
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$ --<< replaces the '
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Following advice on qualifying target columns makes everything easier to read too. *bows*